# Macro running fine in one script but copied version taking 100 times longer

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro script that I have built to take an entry from a database and write the result to a worksheet to then be worked upon by further macros in the workbook.

In an effort to refactor my code, im jigging bits about and making buttons on the front end part to make it sleeker and etc this isn't the important part.

Here is the original code that still works,

```
Sub Test()
Dim xm, dd As Worksheet
    Set dd = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Start Sheet")
    procName = dd.Cells(1, 1).Value
    If procName = "" Then
        MsgBox "There is no value in selected row." & Chr(10) & "Please go to 'Start Sheet' and select a value first.", vbExclamation, "Try again"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set xm = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("The Work Page")
    xm.Cells.Clear

    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim objectName As String
    Dim objectTableCol As Collection
    Set objectTableCol = New Collection
    Dim y As Long
    Dim ExistsFlag As Boolean
    ExistsFlag = False


    Server_Name = "" ' Enter your server name here
    Database_Name = "" ' Enter your database name here
    User_ID = "" ' enter your user ID here
    Password = "" ' Enter your password here
    SQLStr = "SELECT columnname FROM [table name] WHERE name = 'some name of a column'"

    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
    ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic

    'Chr(10) is a NewLine character
    bigarray = Split(rs.Fields("field name to split on"), Chr(10))

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing

'********************************************************* Find Objects!! *******************************************************************************
For i = 0 To UBound(bigarray)
    xm.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = bigarray(i)   'this bit of code writes code to the excel sheet. 
Next i

End Sub
```

this piece of code is called by various macros as a sub routine and notable on the front page from a button. It has no difficulties in running and average run time is about 5-6.5 seconds.

Here is the piece of code I copied from this test module above into another seperate module in the workbook for code refactoring purposes.

---

```
Sub PopulateExcelWithXML()
Dim xm, dd As Worksheet
    Set dd = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Start Sheet")
    procName = dd.Cells(1, 1).Value
    If procName = "" Then
        MsgBox "There is no value in selected row." & Chr(10) & "Please go to 'Start Sheet' and select a process first.", vbExclamation, "Try again"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set xm = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("The Work Page")
    xm.Cells.Clear

    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    Server_Name = "" ' Enter your server name here
    Database_Name = "" ' Enter your database name here
    User_ID = "" ' enter your user ID here
    Password = "s" ' Enter your password here
    SQLStr = "SELECT column name FROM [table name] WHERE name = 'name of some column'" 

    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
    ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic

    'Chr(10) is a NewLine character
    bigarray = Split(rs.Fields("processxml"), Chr(10))

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing

'********************************************************* Find Objects!! *******************************************************************************
For i = 0 To UBound(bigarray)
    xm.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = bigarray(i) 'this bit of code writes code to the excel sheet. used for debugging
Next i

End Sub
```

Now this code is called from the front page through an image that I right clicked and assigned the macro to it. Very straightforward and similar in every respect minus the page they write to, one is a test debugging page and one is a working page. The running time however for this second macro is 20-25 minutes. It's incredibly slow and i have no idea why.

Other information that might help people route out the problem with me. the image works fine on another persons machine, the whole thing is contained in one workbook, the test method never stopped working and the new piece is just a c + v version of it. I dont re-use the sub named test because it's sitting in a test page full of test elements that I want to stay that way, instead i made another sub and copied it so I could adjust that new one as needs without losing old work for testing and debugging. Im running on xp and have tested on win 7, excel is 2010. Im still banging my head against a wall here to figure out what's causing it. The data that I'm pulling back from the DB is a single cell from one row and in it is an entire XML that can be anywhere from 6000 lines to 25000 lines long hence the split from recordset to array to print it out.

I'm not looking for solutions that say just use the test method as it works, I wish to know WHY the other method isn't working correctly to deepen my understanding of the system. Any help appreciated.

Blanked out sensitive fields, they are actually populated just not leaving the details

Comment: It will be hard to determine the cause for this issue, but what you could do is to insert `Debug.Print "Description of what macro is currently doing " & Now()` in few places to both macros and run them. This way you'll get information on at what point the macro slows down.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "one is a test debugging page and one is a working page" - the 2 pieces of code you posted are functionally identical other than the placeholder text and the inclusion of the collections and flag that never get used.

Comment: Wujaszkun, it happens at the For loop at the end part where it iterates over the array. Good shout. Just used Debug.Print i and the printer for the first test module spins through like lightning and the other one goes incredibly slow at that part.

Comintern, I have a module named 'TestPurposes' where I write code to test functionality as I write it or think of it, then copy it over into the actual workbook when im happy with it. I know they are very similar but that is literally what's in my workbook and I can't see why one is slow and one isn't. 1/2

Comment: 2/2 I think the problem here might not be a vba based error but a feeling it's something to do with the way my computer is assigning macros to images (clip art or downloaded images or shapes) but i can't find anything on why that would happen so maybe im wrong on that asumption

Comment: I'd rule out "the way my computer is assigning macros to images". Are the queries the same?

Comment: Query is the exact same, sql query is the same. Is that the query you mean?

Answer (score 1):

If the same code works differently on two different machines, I suspect the code is fine. Perhaps you could add the following around the For loop?

`Application.Calculation = xlManual`

`Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic`

Comment: Hi Michael, That was a good suggestion. Timing has improved by about ~23% but it still isn't as fast as the other piece of code which runs at 5-6 seconds. With this change it runs to about 16-18 minutes instead of 20-25 though!

Comment: Could it just simply be that the test data is so much smaller? Just how much does it have to do in the test compared to the actual job?

Comment: the actual job will be the same size as the test data. parsing xml's anywhere from 6000-12000 lines long and just dump it into a sheet line for line